# Ascending sequence of simply connected sets and their union

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about simply connected sets that might sound quite trivial and easy but i am not sure if my first step of the proof will be sufficient for the whole proof.

So, we have an ascending sequence of simply connected sets $D_{1}\subset D_{2}\subset D_{3}..... $, their intersection is connected and not empty. Show that their union is also simply connected.

I've shown that $D_{1} \cup D_{2}$  is simply connected. (The union of the sets is connected, i show that if the function $F$ on their union is holomorphic, well defined and as being an antiderivative of a function $f$, the set of the union of these two simply connected set is also simply connected.)

I am not sure that this is enough to show about the general union of the ascending set sequence... 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are the sets also assumed to be open? (And I think you wrote intersection where you meant union in the second paragraph.)

Comment: Yes, the sets are open. I meant intersection of $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ is connected and not empty. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the $D_i$ are assumed to be open, we have the following:

Let $f\colon S^1\to \bigcup_i D_i$, then $\mathrm{im}(f)$ is compact and covered by $\bigcup_iD_i$. Hence there is a finite set $I\subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathrm{im}(f)\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I} D_i =  D_{\max(I)}$.

Since $D_{\max(I)}$ is simply connected there is a homotopy $F\colon S^1\times [0,1]\to D_{\max(I)}$ such that $F(\theta,0) = f(\theta)$ and $F(\theta,1)$ is constant. Let $i\colon D_{\max(I)}\to \bigcup_i D_i$ be the natural inclusion, then $i\circ F$ gives the required homotopy on $\bigcup_i D_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider sequence Dn = { e^i*(theta) , where 0<=theta < 2pi-1/n}
clearly each Dn is simply connected, but their union is the unit circle which is not simply connected.

Comment: sorry i did not read the votes, the sets are open huh?

Comment: Yes, the sets are open.