# Union of simply-connected domains is simply-connected

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

Let $(D_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of simply-connected domains in $\mathbb{C}$ so that $D_n\subset D_{n+1}$.
Prove: $D:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_n$ is a simply-connected domain.

I have already shown that G is a domain, but I am struggling with the simply-connectness. Is it easiest to show that every holomorphic function has an antiderivative?
I have already read the following post:
[Ascending sequence of simply connected sets and their union](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379129/ascending-sequence-of-simply-connected-sets-and-their-union). However, the concept of homotopy has not been introduced yet.
Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Definition of homotopy:
Let $\Gamma$ be a cycle in $U$ (open). $\Gamma$ is null homologous in $U$, if $n_{\Gamma}(z)=0 \forall z\in U^c$. (n_{\Gamma}(z) is the number of turns)

Definition of simple Connection:
A domain $D$ is called simply connected, if every cycle in $D$ is null homologous.

Comment: Do you mean $G:=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$?

Comment: Oh, of course, thank you, I change it

Comment: How can you not know homotopy, but ask about simply connected? That doesn't make sense. The definition of simply connected requires the knowledge of homotopy.

Comment: @freakish I was introduced to simply connection based on the homology of cycles

Comment: You should spell out your definition of simple connectivity then.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I edited my post

Comment: I guess $U^c$ is the complement of $U$?

Comment: @hannah2002: You can still use the approach from the referenced answer: If $\Gamma$ is a cycle in $G$ then there is some index $n$ such that $\Gamma$ is contained in $D_n$.

Answer (score 2):

As we know the countable union of open sets is open,also the union is connected when $D_n$ are connected. Take a contour in $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_n$ then its image is a compact set inside an open set.Apply separation Lemma and take integrals in suitable curve to show that int(Γ)$\subset$ int($Γ_1$) where $Γ_1$ is the contour that you find from separation lemma.We condlude in:
$$ \text{int}(Γ)\subset \text{int}(Γ_1)\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_n$$